# How to get current logged in user from WordPress via custom endpoints?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-rest-api, nonce

I have an endpoint in my WordPress plugin, and using it. I want to get the user who is currently logged in the WordPress. My endpoint looks like this:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
register_rest_route( 't2mchat/v2', '/get_curr_user', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_curr_user'
    ));
});
```

The callback function:

```
function get_curr_user(WP_REST_Request $request){    
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  return $user;
}
```

This gives me back user ID as `0`.

I read the article on WordPress official website about [Authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication) , and learned that I need to pass `nonces`, but since I am a new to this, I could not understand everything it says.

Also, I am calling this endpoint in my React app like this:

```
loadData() {
return fetch(`/wordpress/wp-json/t2mchat/v2/get_curr_user`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    this.setState({ curr_user: responseJson });
    //console.log(this.state.curr_user, "curr user role");
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

I am not sure how do I pass `nonces` in the request, so I can get the currently logged in user.

Can anyone with experience/idea suggest what changes I need to make in my code?

An example would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used session storage to store user data when the wordpress initializes and retrieved from my endpoint. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in your PHP file include the wp-load.php

```
include_once("wp-load.php");
```

then you can access to all native Wordpress Function just call them.
So you have to be able to retrieve the current logged in user by wp_get_current_user();